# JSON files fields intersection in JAVA

Tags: java, json

I would like to ask if there are any libraries that allows me to make the intersection of two JSON files at their fields structure? For example, i have incoming json file like this:

```
{
   "name": "John",
   "surname": "Smith",
   "age": 15,
   "address": {
       "street": "Some street",
       "city": "some city",
       "country": "some country",
       "height": 500
   },
   "company": { 
       "name": "Company name",
       "fullname": "Company full name",
       "id": 451,
   },
   "personid": 5412457
}
```

And now i would like to have another json file (template file) like this:

```
{
   "name": "",
   "surname": "",
   "address": {
       "street": "",
       "city": "",
   },
}
```

**And now i want to cut first json file based on the second one**. Is there some simple way how to do this? Thanks

Comment: If you deserialize your json to java object, you will be able to manipulate the structure as standard java object...

Comment: You can use Jackson or Gson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackson ObjectMapper ?

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
FirstClass fc = objectMapper.readValue(jsonstring1), FirstClass.class);
SecondClass sc = new SecondClass(fc);
String jsonstring2 = mapper.writeValueAsString(sc);
```